# SQLite.Interop.dll files does not copy to project output path when required by referenced project

Tags: sqlite, nuget, system.data.sqlite

I am using the System.Data.SQLite Core Version: 1.0.98.1 nuget package with Visual Studio 2015. When I build my project that references my System.Data.SQLite package, it copies two folders (x86 and x64) each containing a SQLite.Interop.dll to the output directory. However when I build my test project or any other project that references the previously mentioned project, these folders do not get copied to the the parent project's output directory, and I get a DllNotFoundException on the SQLite.Interop.dll.

Note: this is specifically when the project referencing System.Data.SQLite is referenced by another project

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The recomended solution as doumented [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/2ed3cad9cc9d5938808816bbc6da92366cd5a4dc) is to create a System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets.user in your packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.98.1\build\[your framework version here] folder containing

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup> 
        <ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>true</ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>
        <CopySQLiteInteropFiles>false</CopySQLiteInteropFiles>
        <CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>
        <CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But if you don't want to add anything in your packages folder to your source control, you can just add the following directly to your project file

```
<PropertyGroup> 
    <ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>true</ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CopySQLiteInteropFiles>false</CopySQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

## **Update for SDK style projects**

In the new SDK project style, there is a change in how dependencies are resolved across nested projects and packages. In the build process, assets are resolved and a `obj\project.assets.json` file is generated listing the assets from all the various dependencies. The project assets file is then used to determine what targets need to be imported and what files need to be copied to the output directory. 
There is, however a difference in how assets are included from non-direct dependencies. Target files from the `build` folder of non-direct dependencies are not imported. The old workaround depends on `System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets` getting imported into the parent project. Projects that directly depend on `System.Data.Sqlite` can override this behavior by adding `PrivateAssets="none"` to the `PackageImport`. You will also need to add this to each PackageImport or ProjectReference` in your dependency chain. However, you won't need to combine this with the prior workaround.

TLDR

In the project that directly references System.Data.Sqlite add `PrivateAssets="none"` to your PackageImport

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.112" PrivateAssets="none"/>
```

For each project in your dependency chain up to your root project also add`PrivateAssets="none"`

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.csproj" PrivateAssets="none"/>
```

Comment: My local builds were working fine -- the CopySQLiteInteropFiles ran and copied files to the OutDir on my machine. But the same build failed during my tests on TeamCity -- Dll not found exceptions on the missing Interop files.
Creating the CopySQLiteInteropFiles properties in my proj file was what worked to get TeamCity to copy the interop files over. +1

Comment: Second solution worked great for me. Doesn't the recommended break as soon as you get a new version say from nuget?

Comment: i have a winform project referencing a SDK project with sqlite, i tried using PrivateAssets="none" both in the sdk and winworm but the winform project doesn't have the interop dll neither in the bin nor publish file list. (vs2019) Any idea?

Comment: ok, so simply adding `PrivateAssets="none"` to each dependency in the chain worked for me! This is also available via VS UI as property on the nuget reference. Note that I didn't do anything for a last non-SDK style project in one of the chains and it worked there as well.

Answer (score 3):

`<ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>true</ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>` seems to have no effect with **.NET Standard 2.0** where `SQLite.interop.dll` is still not recognized as content nor dependency in a referencing project.

I hope someone find a cleaner solution for this...

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard20</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.112" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Fix to get SQLite.interop.dll copied when using netstandard -->
    <Content Include="$(PkgSystem_Data_SQLite_Core)\runtimes\win-x86\native\netstandard2.0\SQLite.Interop.dll" Link="x86\SQLite.Interop.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="$(PkgSystem_Data_SQLite_Core)\runtimes\win-x64\native\netstandard2.0\SQLite.Interop.dll" Link="x64\SQLite.Interop.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: @BenCamps Thanks, that looks cleaner - but as you are saying, that would require all other projects to also set a package attribute, which my current workaround does not.

Comment: However, the new SDK style project format no longer uses the packages folder located in your projects directory. The new packages folder is located in %userprofile%/.nuget/packages. But a cleaner solution would be to use [`GeneratePathsProperty`](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/pull/2271) to create a variable in your project file to reference the package directory where ever it may be.

Comment: @BenCamps aah, thanks for the heads up! I guess my old packages folder is intact since I just upgraded. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This works great but errors arise when creating a nuget package of my project.   NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221, 5): [NU5118] File is not added because the package already contains file 'content\SQLite.Interop.dll'.   NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221, 5): [NU5100] The assembly 'content\SQLite.Interop.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced. Has anyone else run into this?