# Elmah can't find SQLite.Interop.dll

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah

I have ELMAH in an MVC project installed via Nuget and it can't find SQLite.Interop.dll.

> [DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)]
>   System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(SQLiteConfigOpsEnum
>   op) +0    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized() +111
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize() +48
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +55
>   Elmah.SQLiteErrorLog.GetErrors(Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, IList
>   errorEntryList) +338    Elmah.ErrorLogPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +455
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +772

My output directory has the appropriate x86 and x64 directories with the assembly included.

[image]

If I copy one of these into bin, ELMAH works fine.

None of the other devs working on this project are having any issues. We're all using IIS Express locally, VS 2013, and No SQLite binaries in anyone's GAC.

Comment: I think this may be the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639630/sqlite-interop-dll-files-does-not-copy-to-project-output-path-when-required-by-r/32639631#32639631

Answer (score 0):

I've seen several solutions for this:

- Add the SQLite.Interop.dll as an item to your root folder of your web application with 'Build Action' set to Content and 'Copy to Output Directory' set to 'Copy if newer' or 'Copy Always'.  In this case you need to select either the x86 or x64 version to link to depending if your web application is going to run with 32 bit enabled or not.
- Copy the appropriate SQLite.Interop.dll in the post build event.
- Use MSBuild target to copy the appropriate SQLite.Interop.dll.

Comment: I've seen those solutions, I don't understand why it works on other dev machine and not mine.

Comment: Is it possible that they have run one of the [Setups](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) for SQLite?

Comment: I think that's unlikely but i'll look into it. We only use SQLite for Elmah and it's all installed with nuget.