# Couldn't 'Copy Always' SQLite.Interop.dll Visual Studio 2017 community

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, interop

I am working on a WPF using C# project in Visual Studion 2017 and am able to run the project in development mode perfectly. But after I publish the project I got the error Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found.(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

I searched a lot but couldn't find the solution. Many a place people mentioned that to place SQLite.Interop.dll in Debug folder but in my application those dll of x64 and x86 already exists in Debug folder but the next step they said were to change file properties to

**Build Action:** None and

**Copy to output directory**: Copy always

But the problem is I could not find these options when I right click on SQLite.Interop.dll. Please help me in this because I am stuck in this right from bunch of hours. Your's help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you publish your app? Are you using wix, InstallShield?

Comment: From explore create a `Lib` folder under your solution, copy the `SQLite.Interop.dll` file into that. Within VS in the Solution Explorer, right click on Dependencies/References and choose Add Reference and select the `SQLite.Interop.dll` file. It should then be part of your project and the publish.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I published my app in visual studio 2017 by right clicking on my app and selected "Publish" button. I cleaned it before publishing. I am not using wix nor InstallShield.

Comment: @FrankNielsen I already solved this issue by following this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639630/sqlite-interop-dll-files-does-not-copy-to-project-output-path-when-required-by-r/32639631#32639631. But I will also check if your suggestion can help me solve the problem and will reply on that.

Comment: For the sake of someone who's stucking in this problem I would like to post the steps I followed to solve it by following the above link. In Visual Studio 2017 Community version.

Comment: Solution Explorer -> Click Solutions and Folders(button with drop down list) -> Select the option with non-.sln button 
In this select the file with .csproj extension and open it -> Paste the below code in that file under <Project> tab

<PropertyGroup> 
    <ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>true</ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CopySQLiteInteropFiles>false</CopySQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>
</PropertyGroup>

Comment: Edit your question with this information instead. Good find and well done :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Step 1: Click Solutions and Folders Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv3L5.png)

[Step 2: Select Folder View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe8sj.png)

[Step 3: Double Click to Open file with .csproj extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ8AM.png)

[Step 4: Copy, Paste and save the below code inside `<PropertyGroup>` tag like given in the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6XXN.png)

```
<ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>true</ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>
<CopySQLiteInteropFiles>false</CopySQLiteInteropFiles>
<CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>
<CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>
```

[Step 5: Click Solutions and Folders Button and then SELECT button with .sln option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xbpT.png)

[Step 6: Right click on Project and then SELECT Reload Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL75J.png)

[Step 7: If file with .csproj is open then this popup will come and SELECT yes button to close it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12SzF.png)

And this is how my problem solved after ditching the head for one complete day. I hope this will help someone.