# Elmah not creating the SqlLite tables and stored procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, elmah

I'm using Elmah for logging the unhandled exception in ASP.NET MVC using SqlLite database. When i configure the Elmah with SqlLite database using below

```
<elmah>
<!--
    See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
    more information on remote access and securing ELMAH.
-->
<security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
<errorLog type="Elmah.SQLiteErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah" />
</elmah>
```

using below connectionstring

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Elmah" connectionString="data source=~/App_Data/Error.db" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

It throw this exception

```
SQLiteException (0x1): SQL logic error
    no such table: Error]
       System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain) +1239
       System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand() +374
       System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index) +18
       System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult() +309
       System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave) +266
       System.Data.`enter code here`SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +45
       System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader() +21
       Elmah.SQLiteErrorLog.GetErrors(Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, IList errorEntryList) +235
       Elmah.ErrorLogPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +336
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678`
```

Can anybody tell me where i'm wrong?

How i can configure SqlLite database with Elmah for logging?

Comment: Same problem here. I've successfully configured elmah&sqlite locally, running my wcf with visual studio. When I publish to distant IIS server, (some struggling here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32639631/1520739)), it throws the exact same error.
And it seems we have the same web.config, except I have this in `<webServer>` : 
`<handlers>
  <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah/default.aspx" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
</handlers>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
</modules>`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to create the database or run a script manually, since `SQLLiteErrorLog` [does this automatically](https://github.com/elmah/Elmah/blob/1x/src/SQLiteErrorLog.cs#L120). I just tested this and it works by doing this:

1. Create a new web project.
2. Install the [ELMAH](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/) NuGet package.
3. Install the [System.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/) NuGet package.
4. Add the following to `web.config`

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Elmah" connectionString="data source=~/App_Data/Error.db" />
</connectionStrings>

...

<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SQLiteErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah" />
</elmah>
```

5. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> and navigate to `/elmah.axd`.

I did the above steps, as well as forced an exception in one of my controllers and requested that route. The `Error.db` file is successfully created and an error is logged.

If you already have a file named `Error.db` in the `App_Data` folder, try deleting that and retry.