# SQLite Interop Files not copied to Output Directory with MSBuild task 'Clean'

Tags: c#, msbuild, continuous-integration, system.data.sqlite

I have a Project referencing System.Data.SQLite.Core NuGet Package.

I already added the "ContentSQLiteInteropFiles" Tags to my .csproj as recomended in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639630/sqlite-interop-dll-files-does-not-copy-to-project-output-path-when-required-by-r).

Everything works as expected on my local machine within Visual Studio, but my Build-Server keeps not copying the x86 and x64 folders.

On my Build-Server i'm adding this Parameters to MSBuild.exe:

> /t:Clean;Restore;Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=..\bin\Release\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i found [this Visual Stuido Problem Report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/353718/sqliteinteropdll-not-copied.html), i tried to build the Solution localy with the same Parameters that i use on the Build-Server. It turns out the Issue is reproducable on my local machine. If i delete all "obj" Directories in my Solution the first Build does not copy x86/x64, all following Build do copy the Interop Files into the expected Folders. My Build Server is configured to clean up the working copy before each build and so deletes the obj Folders what causes the error.

As the Problem seems to be somehow related to the Clean Task, after switching to

> /t:**Restore;Rebuild** /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=..\bin\Release\

the Build copied the x86 and x64 directories to my output directory as expected on the first build.