# MSTest DeploymentItem attribute causes SQLite.Interop.dll not found

Tags: mstest, visual-studio-2019

The suite of unit tests I have immediately fails the test run with `System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'` which is a dependency required within the test `[AssemblyInitialize]` methods.

I've determined this is caused by executing any test that is using the `[DeploymentItem]` attribute and is the case for either a class or method. Any tests that do not use this attribute pass.

With Test Diagnostic logging enabled in VS2019 there are no obvious errors but I can see this config.

```
 <RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <ResultsDirectory>D:\Dev\****\src\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
    <SolutionDirectory>D:\Dev\****\src\</SolutionDirectory>
    <TargetPlatform>X86</TargetPlatform>
    <CollectSourceInformation>False</CollectSourceInformation>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

My test projects are all configured for `<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>` so I wonder if the `SQLite.Interop.dll` is not found because of an issue with x86 vs x64.

- Where can I configure the `<RunSettings>`?
- Why would `SQLite.Interop.dll` not be found?

**UPDATE**

Using `procmon.exe` filtering for `testhost.exe` and `SQLite.Interop.dll` I can see that a test without `[DeploymentItem]` attributes starts looking for the dll in the project `bin\Debug` folder which finds it at `bin\Debug\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll`.

Those tests with the attribute starts looking in the Test Results directory `TestResults\...\Out` then all across the machine `C:\Windows`, `C:\Program Files`, `C:Users` but never further under `bin\Debug`.

Running the same tests using `VSTest.Console.exe` does not have this issue.

- How can I apply [System.Data.SQLite from NuGet, interop dll not copied to output directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26768005) to the `.\Out` directory for the unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve;

1. [Configure unit tests by using a .runsettings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019)
2. Add setting `<DisableAppDomain>True</DisableAppDomain>`, see [Configure a test run](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/configure.md)

Note that run settings cannot be retained at the project or solution level and need to be set in the IDE; https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/151608/ability-to-set-runsettings-in-project-file.html

Answer (score 1):

[Dave Anderson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57796832/10842976) did help, however we load custom modules into SQLite and this caused the 'Attempted to read or write protected memory' error. The work around for me was to remove `<DisableAppDomain>True</DisableAppDomain>` and use

`[DeploymentItem(@"x86\SQLite.Interop.dll", "x86")]
[DeploymentItem(@"x64\SQLite.Interop.dll", "x64")]`

on all tests or classes that needed to use SQLite